How to combine values ​in one column separated by commas
My code in postgre sql looks like this:
select
ouput.Serial ID as "Serial ID",
   case when ouput.parameters->>'10' = 'true' then 'hello' else '' end as "Hello",
   case when ouput.parameters->>'11' = 'true' then 'World' else '' end as "World"
from ouput
left join company_maintenance_entities abc on abc.id = ouput.maintenance_entity_id 
left join ouput_statuses on issue_statuses.id = ouput.status_id
where
    ouput.parameters->>'10' = 'true' or ouput.parameters->>'11' = 'true'
order by ouput.Serial ID

On output I get



Serial ID
Hello
World




1
hello
World


2

World


3
hello



4

World


5
hello
World


6
hello
World



How can I make query select sure that the Hello and World columns are joined in one column separated by commas and it turns out like this?



Serial ID
hello world




1
hello, world


2
world


3
hello


4
world


5
hello, world


6
hello, world




https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66555257/string-concatenation-using-operator-or-format-function

The more "usual" way of doing this is to combine rows of data, rolling them up to the level you're grouping at, something like this:
select 
  t0.Serial_ID 
, group_concat( t0.value ) as values 
from 
( select
    o.Serial_ID as "Serial ID"
  , 'hello' as value 
    end as value
  from ouput as o 
  left join company_maintenance_entities abc on o.maintenance_entity_id =  abc.id 
  left join ouput_statuses os on o.status_id = os.id 
  where o.parameters->>'10' = 'true' 
  UNION ALL
  select
    o.Serial_ID 
  , 'world' 
  from ouput as o 
  left join company_maintenance_entities abc on o.maintenance_entity_id = abc.id 
  left join ouput_statuses os on o.status_id = os.id 
  where o.parameters->>'11' = 'true' 
) t0 
group by t0.Serial_ID
order by t0.Serial_ID

This can be extended to as many values as you need and will cope with the "All, Either, Neither, None" combinations automatically.
